# How to export admin roles from google Workspace to BigQuery Dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, looker-studio

I am trying to create a dashboard on datastudio to display all roles and permissions that are on our Google Workspace console.
So i created a project on GCP and a dataset on BigQuery, but i have no clue how to export/load those datas (admin roles) on BigQuery.
Maybe with a cloud function ? Do i need a Client Oauth 2.0 or a service account ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to setup the in-built export from Workspace to BigQuery.
The configuration is described [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365).

After a day, you should have your data populated.

Then you should identify if there is a proper filter to get out exactly the roles that you are interested. Please be aware the export data is auditlog, so it might be many entries for the same account.

Unfortunately I don't have access to a full schema and data example to give you the right filter, but with a bit of study you should be able to build it out.

The following audit logs are supported:

- Accounts
- Admin
- and many others

the full list is available [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365#supportedServices&zippy=%2Cwhat-services-does-bigquery-export-support).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Unfortunately, a BigQuery export is already set up in my organization and i can't use it.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use it? That should be your first choice for this kind of data.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i can now use it but datas in Workspace and datas in this BigQuery export don't match so i need an other option i think